# Q : std::function with different type inside the same array

Tags: c++, performance, caching, metaprogramming, std-function

I'm working on an [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system) library for learning purpose, and I'm trying to make major changes to my design.

I'm going to split the `class System` with one `update` call to several `update` functions. But these functions could be anything, function menber or not. So I ended with a lot of different `std::function` type.

For performance reason, I don't really want to use a `tuple` (or maybe it's really efficient, tell me). I'd like to use an `std::array`, but how can I put every kind of `std::function` together? Well in fact it's a `struct` which contain `std::function`, but because of that the `struct` get the same type problem.

And if the array could be generate at **compile time** (whih no arguments) it will be the best.

There is an illustration(not real code) of how I'd like it to work.

```
//Function to add a function in the list [[Call by User]]
addSystemBloc<Position, Speed>(function(ArgIDontKnow, Position, Speed), otherThings);

//Function to generate a structure (probably a graph) linked to the array
generateGraph();

//Inside the initialization of the System using the function we just add [[ Call by User ]]
addArgument(id, arg); //id is not really nice, and this guy know the function he wants to add an arg (with std::bind)

//Somwhere in the main loop [[ Call by Library ]]
invoke(func, Position, Speed);
```

Anyway thanks

Comment: You want an array that has different types in it? You can't. All elements of an array are the same. What performance problems are you worried  about with tuple? Tuples have no overhead.

Comment: How are you planning to discover the type of these functions so you can call them? (If each position has a fixed type, that's a tuple.)

Comment: Perhaps [Boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [Boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/any.html) (or their upcoming standard-library variants [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any))? Not that I really recommend those though, instead I'd rather recommend you try to rethink your design (while you're still working on it).

Comment: I know that it's impossible, that's why I'm asking how to do it (some workaround) for this case. I don't know if tuple are cache friendly, I think no, but not sure. I'm going to add a illustration, maybe it'll help.

Comment: Another possible way might be to use only a single function type which uses a generic pointer (i.e. `void*`) to pass the actual data to the function.

Comment: @molbdnilo all I need is to add missing arguments which I know must be there. Just put in the function and call it, that's all my library will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is a fixed length sequence of values of specified type. 
A tuple is a fixed length sequence of values of specified types.
A struct with no methods is a fixed length sequence of values of specified types.

These all have the same performance characteristics with regard to retrieving elements (i.e. constant), and moving / copying (i.e. sizeof(Thing) bytes).

What "performance problems" are you imagining?

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object

Comment: So you mean than tuple are contiguous memory too, and there is no cache problem like an array?

Comment: Yes, by the rules of object layout

Comment: Oh well, I wasn't able to be sure about that thanks :) tuple are so powerfull then oO I need to see their cons. If you have a link to illustrate the rules of object layout I'll close this with your answer.